# How can I update 2 different Access databases from one dataset?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dataset, oledbconnection, tableadapter

I currently have a datagridview that is data bound to a local Access database.  The form that holds the datagridview allow users to add or remove records and then update the database.

This all works like a charm.  The part where I am having trouble is after the first database is successfully updated, I then want to update the master database as well that is located in a different directory.

Basically I create a new connection and then change the local connection (original) to the new database.  I then update the database and close the connection.  When I step through the code I can see that the new database is getting opened properly yet nothing happens when the Update command executes.  I close the connection, watch the new database close on screen, and then exit the app.

When I open the new database, nothing has changed.

Is using a dataset from one database to update a different, yet identical database possible?  I don't get any errors when running, just a database that opens but does not update.

```
Private Sub UpdateMasterDatabase()

    'Create a connection to the Master database and open it
    Dim masterConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(MASTER_DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING & MASTER_DATABASE_FILEPATH & MASTER_DATABASE_NAME)
    masterConnection.Open()

    'Change the connection from the Local database to the Master database
    TeamProjectsTableAdapter.Connection = masterConnection

    'Update the Master database
    Me.TeamProjectsTableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSetDVM.TeamProjects)

    'Close the connection
    masterConnection.Close()
    masterConnection = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: You know you could just copy the updated DB to the other directory.

Comment: I considered that but what if someone else is trying to do the same thing?

Comment: You should probably write some sort of run-once applet or service that backs up the DB once a day rather than doubling up on every single DB operation.  What happens when updating the second fails for some reason?

Comment: ok, that makes sense but even so, how does that resolve my issue of updating it the 2nd DB?  My thought process was to pull down the data from the 2nd DB to a local DB, then perform whatever actions and update the local DB, and then once that is successful, update the 2nd DB.  (I'm referring to the Master DB as the 2nd DB)

Comment: Is `Me.DataSetDVM.TeamProjects` the table that was used to update the local DB?  Is so, after that update, any changes to the table were marked as accepted and hence there are no changes to send as far as it is concerned.  You can create a DataTable of the changed records by calling  `Me.DataSetDVM.TeamProjects.GetChanges`.

Comment: Thanks, Tn.  How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Also, I would add that I had to cast Me.DataSetDVM.TeamProjects.GetChanges into a DataSetDVM.TeamProjectsDataTable.